# Next js + netelify ( app router ) page reloads in navigatin

Tags: javascript, next.js, deployment, netlify

When i hosted the nextjs 13.4.6 app (using app router for navigatiion) in netlify, the page reload while navigating from one page to another but same code works fine in vercel, Is it my own code mistake or netlify doesn't support app router ?

Comment: No sure, but the issue is discussed by others in this GitHub issue, so am assuming it's something on Netlify's side: https://github.com/netlify/next-runtime/discussions/1724#discussioncomment-4606276 - Stick to Vercel?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is bug from the netlify here is the ongoing discussion: https://github.com/netlify/next-runtime/issues/2089

Comment: this could have been a comment

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35527344)